# php forms return data back to .html page

Tags: php, forms, post, return

This should be a pretty simple questions but I can't seam to find a simple answer. All of the questions I find deal with same jquery.

I have a php page that accepts for post data, places it in an array, passes the array to an api, and receives success/error from api.

I have an html page with a form. When I submit the form it passes the form data to the php file.

All I would like to do is return the success/error message's variable back to the html file. I don't care if the page reloads, I don't want any fancy features I'm just trying to do a simple test but have forgotten my php 101. any help or direction to references would be appreciated.

Html:

```
<div style="width: 400px; margin: 150px auto;">

    <form action="api3.php" method="post">
       <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="fname"><br><br>

       <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="lname"><br><br>

       <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email"><br><br>

       <input type="text" placeholder="Phone" name="phone"><br><br>

       <select name="life"><br><br>
         <option value="customer">Customer</option>
         <option value="lead">Lead</option>
         <option value="subscriber">Subsciber</option>
         <option value="opportunity">Opportunity</option>
       </select><br><br>

       <input type="text" placeholder="Pizza" name="pizza"><br><br>

       <input type="submit" value="Submit">

     </form>

</div>
```

PHP:

```
<?php 

$arr = array(
    'properties' => array (
        array(
        'property' => 'email',
        'value' => $_POST["email"]
        ),
        array(
        'property' => 'firstname',
        'value' => $_POST["fname"]
        ),
        array(
        'property' => 'lastname',
        'value' => $_POST["lname"]
        ),
        array(
        'property' => 'phone',
        'value' => $_POST["phone"]
        ),
        array(
          "property" => "lifecyclestage",
          "value" => $_POST["life"]
        ),
        array(
          "property" => "pizza",
          "value" => $_POST["pizza"]
        )
    )
);

$post_json = json_encode($arr);
$hapikey = "/";
$endpoint1 = 'http://api.hubapi.com/contacts/v1/contact/createOrUpdate/email/' . $arr['properties'][0]['value'] . '/?hapikey=' . $hapikey;
$endpoint2 = 'http://api.hubapi.com/contacts/v1/lists/5/add?hapikey=' . $hapikey;
$ch = @curl_init();
@curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
@curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_json);
@curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint1);
@curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
@curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response1 = @curl_exec($ch);
$status_code1 = @curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$curl_errors1 = curl_error($ch);

if ($status_code1 == 200) {

    $vid = json_decode($response1, true);

    echo $vid['vid'] . '<br><br><br>';

    $arr2 = array(
         'vids' => array (
            $vid['vid']
            )
        ); 

    $vids_push = json_encode($arr2);

    @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $vids_push);
    @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint2);
    $response2 = @curl_exec($ch);
    $status_code2 = @curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $curl_errors2 = curl_error($ch);
    @curl_close($ch);

    return $response2;
}

 ?>
```

**EDIT:** I changed my form.html page to .php. I didn't want to share my code because it always seams to complicate things but all I want is to return $response2 back to my form.php page.

Comment: please put your in which you tried this thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all the page you have form and want to get response should be with .php

Now for example, I have a page with form at www.example.com/work.php

```
//Your form here
<form>   </form>
```

submit the form on other .php page that process input and get response from API.
at the end of page you have two methods to return data.

1. using GET
   encode your variables in url and redirect page to work.php

   $url = "www.example.com/work.php" + "?status=error&message=This is message";
   header('Location: '.$url);

Now on work.php file you need to utilize these parameters we encoded with url using

```
echo $_GET['status'];
echo $_GET['message'];
// rest of the page will be same.
```

2. using SESSION

store variables in session and redirect to work.php without parameters

```
$_SESSION['status'] = "error";
$_SESSION['message'] = "This is message";
$url = "www.example.com/work.php";
header('Location: '.$url);
```

Again in work.php file display data from session and rest of code will be same.

Comment: Thanks for the clear and simple answer. I couldn't do anything with sessions but I was able to see the response in the url using the GET method which is all I was after. Thanks again.